# INSERT-only tables?

Tags: postgresql

I know I could stop normal users from using UPDATE and DELETE by revoking permissions.

No-one (including DB admins) should be able to UPDATE or DELETE from these tables.  (This is for a write-model in CQRS.)

I understand that tables will still be droppable.

How can I create append-only tables in Postgres?

Comment: @mustaccio Yes, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the owner of an object (and a superuser) can drop a table or grant permissions on it.

So keep superusers and table owners under lock and key and don't grant `UPDATE` and `DELETE` to anybody else.

There is no way to protect yourself from a superuser, and protecting yourself from the table owner is difficult.